# Residual set and with its dense subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A set $M\subset\Bbb R$ is called a meager set if it is a countable union of nowhere dense sets. $R\setminus M$ is callled co-meager or resduial set. $R\setminus M$ has a cardinality continuum and it is dense in $\Bbb R$. Moreover, The intersection of two residual sets is still dense.

Notice that this is not true for two dense sets, for instance, $R\setminus\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q$.

> Let $D\subset\Bbb R$ be a residual set and $E\subset D$ is dense in $D$. Is $D\setminus E$ still dense in $D$?

I think, it is not but it did not see this immediately by example

Comment: Isn't $E=D$ already a counterexample?

Comment: @NateEldredge, how about $E\neq D$

Comment: Then let $E$ equal $D$ with one non-isolated point removed.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I think you are right. Thank you

Comment: @NateEldredge, I forgot one important condition which is $E$ does not contain any  interval.

Comment: So then it can go either way depending on what $D$ is.  If $D = \mathbb{R}$ for instance then if $E$ contains no interval, $D \setminus E$ will clearly be dense in $D$.  But if $D = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ then we can take $E = \mathbb{R} \setminus (\mathbb{Q} \cup \{\pi\})$.

Comment: @NateEldredge, Let $I$ be an open interval. If  $I\cap D\neq\emptyset$ then $I \cap E\neq\emptyset$. So, why $E$ in your last statement?

Comment: @NateEldredge, Why $E$ not dense in $D$ in your last statement.

Comment: With the $D = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ example, $E$ **is** dense in $D$.  But $D \setminus E$ is not dense in $D$.  Isn't that the counterexample you wanted?

Comment: @NateEldredge, Okay, How about we change the condition to $E$ does not any perfect set. since your $E$ in the last example contains a perfect set.

Comment: @NateEldredge,  did you see my last comment.

Comment: If $E$ contains no perfect set then it has at least one isolated point, call it $x$.  If $E$ is to be dense in $D$, then $x$ must also be an isolated point of $D$.  But this is impossible if $D$ is residual - there would be some open set such that $U \setminus \{x\}$ is disjoint from $D$, but $U \setminus \{x\}$ is nonmeager.  So these conditions cannot occur.

Comment: @NateEldredge, by these conditions occur . you meant we can not have $E\subset D$ and do not contain any perfect set. Could you please explain.

Comment: Actually I may have made a mistake in what I said before - I forgot that perfect sets are required to be closed.  (Though I'm unclear whether you mean it to be closed in $\mathbb{R}$, or in $D$, or in $E$.)  Anyway I'm afraid I do not have more time to think about it right now.

Comment: @NateEldredge,   I think I figure it out. The intersection of every interval with a co-meager set contains a perfect set. So, we removed from $D$ a set $E$ which does not contain any perfect set. Of course, $D\setminus E$ dense in $D$